# How to make object type from an object keys in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an js object with two keys, `foo` and `bar`.

```
const x = { foo: '', bar: '' }
```

Also I have `abc` function that take value (the value can be `foo` or `bar` only).

```
function abc(value: string) {

 const selected = x[value];
}
```

currently, value is string type. but I want to have `foo` or `bar` (cause I have them in `x` object).
I try to do with

```
  function abc(value: typeof x)
```

But typescript doesn't accept that.

How can I change my code to make it work as I expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use keyof the typeof X, it will extract each key of the type of the variable X which are :

```
{
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}
```

This function has to be :

```
  function abc(value: keyof typeof x)
```

The type of the value param will be `"foo" | "bar"`